# Find Kullback-Leibler distance between two densities

Tags: st.statistics, data-analysis

can someone help me with this exercise? (look at the image). How can I find Kullback-Leibler distance between this two densitie? I have no idea how to arrive at the solution. Every suggestion is welcome. Thanks!  [kullback-leibler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L9ep.jpg)